# Which one should i use “ five cm open or open by five cm “?

Tags: adjectives

Which sentence below is correct ? If both of it wrong please correct me .

> Leave the door five cm open.
>
> Leave the door open by five cm.

Answer (score 2):

Either will be OK, the second is possibly more formal, but in anything except brief notes, one would write measurements in full (e.g. "five centimetres").

Comment: And if you're using "cm", you're almost certainly using numerals as well: "5 cm".  Mixing spelled-out numbers with abbreviated units does indeed look weird.

Comment: "Leave the door open 5 cm" is also ok. And if you're writing out "cm" for an American audience, make sure to spell it "centimeters". (I agree with both this answer and the previous comment.)